# Regex to match conan dependency from conanfile.txt

Tags: java, regex, conan

I am trying to create a regex in Java to match and get the name, version, channel and owner for each dependency but I haven't been able to have one that covers all the possible scenarios:

the structure is something like `name/version@owner/channel`, where the version might have a semver structure, the owner and channel are optional.

Currently, I have :

```
^(?<name>[\d\w][\d\w\+\.-]+)\/(?<version>[\d\w][\d\w\.-]+)(@(?<owner>\w+))?(\/(?<channel>.+))?$
```

but it's failing for `boost_atomic/1.59.0+4@owner/release`, since the `+4` is not matched and I need the value before that -> `1.59.0`

Some other scenarios that need to be valid and are valid for the regex above are:

```
Poco/1.9.0@pocoproject/stable
zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
freetype/2.10.1/stable
openssl/1.0.2g/stable
openssl/1.0.2g
openssl/1.0.2g@owner
```

Also, there might be some dependencies with comments :

`zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable # comment`

In that case I would need to get rid of the component and only get the relevant information with the regex.

I am not sure if my current regex is good, but from what I've tested only some scenarios are missing

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex and avoid putting too many characters in that character set and escaping them, instead use something like `[^\/]` to capture anything except `/` as you want to capture anything preceding a slash.

I've made some modifications and the updated regex that should work for you is following,

```
^(?<name>[^\/]+)\/(?<version>[^\/@\s]+)(@(?<owner>\w+))?(\/(?<channel>\S+))?(?:\s*#\s*(?<comment>.+))?$
```

I've added another named group for comment as you mentioned that can also be present. Let me know if this works for you.

[Try this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC2UT9/1)

Edit: If channel contains a text like `release:132434` and anything followed by a colon is to be ignored as part of channel, you can use updated regex below,

```
^(?<name>[^\/]+)\/(?<version>[^\/@\s]+)(?:@(?<owner>\w+))?(?:\/(?<channel>[^:\s]+)\S*)?(?:\s*#\s*(?<comment>.+))?\s*$
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC2UT9/2)

Comment: Checking more examples I see that the channel might be something like `/release:132434' basically: followed by a string, is there a way to remove that value and only get the channel value?

Comment: Yes, as you said, you might have a colon separated string which you don't want to capture as channel, you can do that. I'll update my answer to include that in my regex